# Qt C++ — как создать виджет, который можно прикрепить и открепить от окна? (сделать отдельным)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Эта функция есть вроде бы в среде разработки Visual Studio, где окна можно откреплять от рабочей части и они становились отдельными.

Как я это представляю: у меня в `QWidget` есть виджет, и если кликнуть на его верхнюю часть - появляется подсветка, которая намекает на то, что его можно сдвинуть. Если этот виджет потянуть вниз, то он становится отдельным окном (с самого виджета он пропадает). И это всё должно работать и в обратную сторону: если этот виджет перетащить к определённой части, появится подсветка, которая намекает, что это окно можно прикрепить к виджету и они станут одним целым.

Простите, объяснил как смог.

Comment: похоже, что вам надо https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html

Comment: Спасибо!Это решает мою проблему